# Using a signal to interrupt the main thread

Tags: c, sockets, server, client, signals

I'm making a server/client TCP concurrent program in C. Everytime a client connects, the main thread of the server creates a new thread, to handle that client. After that, the main thread goes back to accept(), and stays stuck until another client connects.

However, I want the client to be able to close the server. For that, I assume I have to use signals. How can I approach this. I'm very new to signals. I don't know how to send a signal to a specific thread, or how I can use them here.

I want the client to write '..' and close the server.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].  Any thread in your server can call `exit()` to terminate the program.  What you really need to be thinking about, is how your thread can signal all the the other threads, that a shutdown is imminent, so they can exit gracefully, without loosing or destroying data.  That can be as simple as a global flag somewhere, that they all check frequently.

Comment: @jwdonahue if there is no explicit requirement for the threads to exit 'gracefully', there is no need to waste effort on designing, developing, testing, debugging and maintaining such termination, (at least, with non-trivial operating systems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I understood your question, what puzzles me is, where do you use such a server ?. In any case, I hope you will make a good use of this server.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void sigfunc(int signo)
{
    _exit(0); // safe to call in signal handler since it is async-signal-safe func
}

struct client_data {
    int clifd;
    pthread_t ptid;
};

void* client_func(void* _cli_data)
{
    struct client_data* cli_data = (struct client_data*) _cli_data;

    char buf[100];

    for( ; ; ) {
        int rd_status = read(cli_data->clifd, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1);

        if (rd_status <= 0)
            break;

        buf[rd_status] = '\0';
        printf("%s", buf);
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    close(cli_data->clifd);

    pthread_kill(cli_data->ptid, SIGRTMIN);
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    /* Setup a Listening server */

    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(8008);

    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &servaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) != 0)
        exit(1);

    listen(sockfd, 5);

    /* Setup signal handler, use SIGRTMIN as sync signal */

    struct sigaction act;
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_flags = 0;

#ifdef SA_INTERRUPT
    act.sa_flags |= SA_INTERRUPT;
#endif

    act.sa_handler = sigfunc;

    sigaction(SIGRTMIN, &act, NULL);

    /* Loop and listen for connections */

    int addr_len;

    for ( ; ; ) {
        struct client_data cli_data;

        cli_data.ptid = pthread_self();
        addr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        cli_data.clifd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &servaddr, &addr_len);

        if (cli_data.clifd < 0)
            continue;

        pthread_t tid;
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, client_func, &cli_data);
    }
}
```

Terminal Session:

Server

```
$ gcc SO.c -lpthread
$ ./a.out 
Hi to the server
Bye to the server
$
```

Client

```
$ netstat -l | grep 8008 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8008            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
$ nc 127.0.0.1 8008
Hi to the server
Bye to the server
^C
$
```

The code is commented, and you can go through it. As @MartinJames said, you don't need to take a pain of terminating threads where it is absolutely unnecessary, you are better off relying on OS routines. Since we are handling the signals in an asynchronous way, only a few functions can be called in signal handler (async-signal-safe functions); `_exit()` is one among them.

Comment: Yes, I was not using sigaction(), that was the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Alcachofra Since you are new to the community, please give a refresh to this link, [someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)